# How to restrict no one disable trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, database-trigger

I create trigger on table Before Insert or Update. I know user can disable the trigger with Alter trigger disable option. I want any user even SYS user restrict to disable the Specific Trigger. I am using Oracle Database 11g.

How to achieve this target?

Thanks

Comment: you can disable for non-SYS users. Disabling for SYS, as being the super admin user , is a contradiction.

Comment: To forbid SYS being able to do something to your objects, you'll need DB Vault. Otherwise, you can try the solution propose din the answer, it will make life harder for admins, but it's not bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

a `DDL` trigger is needed for `database` :

```
create or replace trigger trg_ddl before ddl on database
declare
  v_oty          varchar2(75) := ora_dict_obj_type;
  v_evt          varchar2(75) := ora_sysevent;
  v_olu          varchar2(75) := nvl(ora_login_user,'Undetermined Schema');
begin     
  if ( nvl(v_evt,'X--|') = 'ALTER' and nvl(v_oty,'Y-|') = 'TRIGGER' 
                                   and nvl(olu,'Z|--|') not in ('SYS','SYSTEM') ) then 
    raise_application_error( -20900 ,'Forbidden Operation');
  end if; 
end;
```